# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Unix & Linux breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6         28
Users destroyed                                  58          0
Users deleted                                    49          0
Users contacted                                   8          0
User banned from review                           2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           297     13,656
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              240      4,514
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        106     13,444
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               41      5,429
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               188     21,442
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              560     29,795
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          7
Tag synonyms created                              3          2
Tag highlight language set                        1          0
Revisions redacted                               12          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                              134        179
Questions protected                               6        147
Questions migrated                               79        175
Questions merged                                  6          0
Questions flagged⁴                               23      2,491
Questions closed                              1,129      7,063
Question flags handled⁴                         588      1,926
Posts unlocked                                    8         81
Posts undeleted                                  50        784
Posts locked                                      9        504
Posts deleted⁵                                2,298     13,679
Posts bumped                                      0      8,727
Escalations to the CM team                       20          0
Comments undeleted                              107          0
Comments flagged                                  6      7,879
Comments deleted⁶                             6,696     19,621
Comment flags handled                         3,170      4,715
Answers flagged                                  53      8,514
Answer flags handled                          4,932      3,635
All comments on a post moved to chat             35          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: /me figures users destroyed by contact with some unfree software. It looks like complaints about comments and answers give moderators a lot of work!