# Is it okay to post, here on meta, a simple Thank You to our moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I would just like to write a very large "Thank you" to our moderators here, past and present.  Things I've recently discovered on other sites across SE have brought into sharp focus the way U&L runs so smoothly.

I've been a forum addict since long before the days of Stackoverflow and I've always been aware how important good moderators are to a community.  Without them forums of any kind (even Stack exchange ones) become cliquey, sour, and eventually die.

I think it's a great credit to all the moderators here, past and present, that U&L remains a largely healthy community where technical discussion (even debate sometimes) is encouraged.  I wholly believe that they have been even handed, tolerant, polite, and above all respectful to the wishes of the community.

I know in the past I may have been [quite vocally] opposed to an occasional decision here.  I now wholly regret not taking the opportunity at the time to express how well I believe our moderators are doing generally.

So yeah... Thanks!

Comment: Aww, thanks! For obvious reasons I will not offer an opinion on whether this is on topic and will leave that to the community. No matter what the voting decides on whether posting this is appropriate, I can tell you that I, at least, appreciate the sentiment behind it :)

Answer (score 13):

Since this is a Q&*A* site, this calls for an answer, and since I’m not a moderator I don’t have the same qualms as terdon!

I think this is OK, and in fact fits quite well [under](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

> Meta is for **Unix & Linux Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other** about Unix & Linux Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)

It’s not “asking a question” as such but it is communicating.

(And thank you to the moderators, and to all the non-moderators who contribute to the general atmosphere here!)

Comment: We are not only "askers" and "answerers", we are human in the end, a community of humans. I think it's only healthy from time to time to express that humanity, and the best of it like being thankful. (Well, except bots and AI ^^).

Answer (score 4):

From a general standpoint, I believe that whatever topic supported by the community has full rights to stand where it stands.

For the sole sake of niggling, I might suggest that it could eventually have found an even better place as an answer to the [2022: a year in moderation](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/2022-a-year-in-moderation) thread which just suggests the deserved thanks OP mentions but… not only, since it outlines the help from :

- *"the non-moderators who contribute to the general atmosphere here!"* as Stephen rightly added to the list,
- Some community-manager(s) that were directly involved at least twice, should'nt we be thankful to them as well ?

Let' niggle even more : I personally find hard to be thankful to abstractions and *moderators* is an abstraction. As *schrodingerscatcuriosity* wrote it in a comment, they are individual human beings and I find it more meaningful to thank them individually, therefore :

Many thanks *Jeff Schaller*, *Kusalananda*, *slm* and *terdon*.
Many thanks to *anonymous_community-manager*
Many thanks to *Philip*, *Stephen* and *schrodingerscatcuriosity* (list made that short only for staying… on topîc… ;-P)